# Running separate in large dataset with R

Tags: r, tidyr, large-data

I'm trying to separate a Date & Time column in a large dataset so that I can isolate merely the time portion.

The column is formatted like this:

```
$ Start_Time <chr> "12/31/2015 05:35:00 PM", "12/31/2015 05:37:00 PM", "12/31/2015 05:37:00 PM", "12/31/2015 05:38:00...
```

I run this line of code:

```
separate(Start_Time, into = c("Date", "Time", "Eh"))
```

And I get the following output.

```
> Test <- Divvy_Trips %>%
+   separate(Start_Time, into = c("Date", "Time", "Eh"))
Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)
```

My session info is below as well:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default
```

Any ideas on what I can do for this to work, or am I out of luck using R given that my dataset is ~21 million observations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just came across `tidytable` while dealing with a similar issue. It has a tidyverse-like and compatible `separate.` function with data.table speed.

```
library(tidytable)

separate.(col = Start_Time, into = c("Date", "Time", "Eh"), sep = " ", extra = "merge)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following `data.table` options :

```
library(data.table)
library(splitstackshape)

setDT(Divvy_Trips)

#Using tstrsplit
Divvy_Trips[, c("Date", "Time", "Eh") := tstrsplit(type, " ")]

#Using cSplit
result <- cSplit(Divvy_Trips, "Start_Time", " ")
```